# Enable gestures ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, augmented-reality, arkit

I've already asked a similar question here => [Enabling gestures in RealityKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64182764/enabling-gestures-in-realitykit)

But I can't solve my problem: I have a custom 3DModel. The improvement I've made since the last question is that it is now a .reality model. I've enabled physics and animation on it.

But if I develop the solution from the previous question I receive a crash since it is not able to downcast my Entity to HasCollision.

I've read some solution where my model is embedded in a sort of container which conform to the various protocol so I can installGesture. But I would like a better approach.

I've tested my model with `ARQuickLook` and all the gesture and animation are set correctly.

P.s.

If I add my model I've an animation that I've added , but I really can't installGesture to my model. But it is .reality!

So my question is: How do I installGesture to a custom 3DModel (.reality) from code?

```
@discardableResult func installGestures(_ gestures: ARView.EntityGestures = .all,
                       for entity: HasCollision) -> [EntityGestureRecognizer]
```

I add some code for reference but it's quiete similar to my previous question.

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {
            
    if let modelEntity = model.modelEntity {
                
        let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(plane: .horizontal)
        
        anchorEntity.addChild(modelEntity.clone(recursive: true))
        
        uiView.scene.addAnchor(anchorEntity)
        
        // modelEntity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true) 
        // If we have multiple object, recursive true help to generate collision for all of them
        
        uiView.installGestures(.rotation, for: modelEntity as! Entity & HasCollision)
        
        uiView.debugOptions = .showPhysics
        
    } else {
        
        print("Unable to load model")
        
    }
}
```