# Having issue with ARView installGestures

Tags: ios, swiftui, arkit, realitykit, arview

I am creating an ARView using `UIViewRepresentable` in SwiftUI, and I am trying to apply all `EntityGestures` to the model, but I am not sure why the gestures are not working and the `ARView` is not receiving any gestures. Here is the code:

```
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
    
        let view = ARView()
        .
        .
        .
        .
        
        // Handle ARSession events via delegate
        context.coordinator.view = view
        session.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(ARCoordinator.handleTap)))
        
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: ARView, context: Context) { }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> ARCoordinator {
        ARCoordinator()
    }
}


class ARCoordinator: NSObject, ARSessionDelegate {
    
    weak var view: ARView?
    var focusEntity: FocusEntity?
    private var isModelPlaced = false
    
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        guard let view = self.view else { return }
        debugPrint("Anchors added to the scene: ", anchors)
        self.focusEntity = FocusEntity(on: view, style: .classic(color: .yellow))
    }
    
    @objc func handleTap() {
    
        if isModelPlaced == false {
            guard let view = self.view, let focusEntity = self.focusEntity else { return }
            // Create a new anchor to add content to
            let anchor = AnchorEntity()
            view.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
            
            // Add a model
            let modelEntity = try! ModelEntity.loadModel(named: "Models.scnassets/ball")
            modelEntity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
            modelEntity.position = focusEntity.position
        
            view.installGestures(.all, for: modelEntity) //*** gestures is not working ***///
            
            focusEntity.hide()
            isModelPlaced = true
            anchor.addChild(modelEntity)
        }
    }
}
```

any help would be great

Comment: It is not clear where is the problem and code is not testable. Is your `handleTap` called on tap?

Comment: Yes, It taps and adds the model, here is the file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mmbe6yw6v2mhjd4/RealityKitView.swift?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, adding gestures to imported 3D models does not work the same as for simple generated shapes. Your code would work fine if you had a ModelEntity with a mesh of GenerateBox or GenerateSphere. I'm not sure why the process is different for imported models, though.

Here's a link to another question that might help: [Enabling gestures in RealityKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64182764/enabling-gestures-in-realitykit)

Someone on the apple developer forum had the same problem. If you can't find what you're looking for in the linked question above, this is your next best bet: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/119773

Am I correct that your code is from [Mohammad Azam's Udemy course](https://www.udemy.com/course/building-augmented-reality-apps-in-realitykit-arkit/learn/lecture/31725712#questions) on RealityKit? If neither of those links work, you might have luck asking him directly in the Q&A.